# Get environment variable in shared razor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to change my razor layout depending on a environment variable.

What is the best way to get an environment variable available in a shared _layout.cshtml file so I can change the layout depending on that variable?

Probably I need some dependency injection, but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Do You want to change main _Layout.cshtml page?

Comment: @HardikMasalawala, yes, for example, I have a Environment Variable [IsTest] and I want to set the page background inside _layout.cshtml through an if statement: ```if (IstTest) background="red"```

Comment: You want one variable you can access in whole app?

Comment: @HardikMasalawala that would probably be the case.

Comment: Are we have different web.config for the different environments?

Comment: yes, each environment has the variable [IsTest]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202619/discussion-between-hardik-masalawala-and-intrixius).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I can use the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable for this: 
I set this in the Azure Web App Configuration, or in Visual Studio in the project properties under Debug - Environment variables.

Then, in _layout.cshtml I use the following

```
<environment names="Test">
    <h1 class="display-4">Test Environment!</h1>
</environment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution if it is suitable for your problem

Add this in your `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="IsTest" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

You can access web.config key value in variable in `Razor view` or in `Controller` like below

```
@{
    var IsTest = Convert.ToBoolean(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsTest"]);

    if(IsTest)
    { 
          // true section 
    }else
    {
          // false section 
    }

}
```

> For ASP.NET CORE:

Please refer this link 
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-environment-variable